# When can a sum of 3 identical squares be written as a sum of 3 non-identical squares?

Tags: integers, sums-of-squares

Consider $3n^2$ for some positive integer $n$. When do there exist positive integers $n_1,n_2,n_3$, **not all equal to** $n$, such that
$$
3n^2 = n_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_3^2
$$
An example is $27$:
$$
27 = 3^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 5^2
$$

Comment: So, your Q is just for the case of $3$ squares?

Comment: Yes (also see edit)

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest the title: When can a sum of 3 identical squares be written as a sum of 3 distinct squares?

Comment: Ah good catch -- edit made! Thank you!

Comment: Is this a sum of three *distinct* squares $1^2 + 1^2 + 5^2$ ? See also https://oeis.org/A004432

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak This suggestion is incorrect, the OP clearly stated: "not all equal to n" which is not quite the same as "three distinct $n_i$"

Comment: @BeaNoether Not sure what the initial title was but maybe it was better.

Comment: To @peter.petrov : English is not my mother language, but still I do not see an error in my suggestion...

Comment: It appears to me that the answer is: whenever $n$ is not a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I have one hint:

$(n-\alpha)^2 + (n- \alpha)^2 + (n+\alpha)^2 = n^2 -2n\alpha + \alpha^2 + n^2 -2n\alpha + \alpha^2 + n^2 +2n\alpha + \alpha^2 = \\ n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + 3\alpha^2 - 2n\alpha.$

So, if we want for the sum to have $3n^2$, then it is mandatory that we have $3\alpha^2-2n\alpha =0 \iff 3\alpha = 2n$, i.e. $\alpha = \frac{2n}{3}$.

Finally, the hint will work in a case when $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: In the question the phase "not all equal to n" is used, thus $3\times5^2=7^2+5^2+1^2$ is valid using this criterion. In general two of the squares don't have to be equal and one of the squares can equal $n$. An example with 3 different squares all not equal to $n$ is $3\times7^2=11^2+5^2+1^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than your question asks (my high-school calculus teacher would **kill** me for answering more than the question asked!), but…

Using well-known parameterizations for the 2.3.3 equation (cf. Bradley, *etc.*), here’s a complete formula in integers $r,s,t,u,v$:
\begin{align}
  n &= \frac{(r^2+s^2+t^2)(rv-su)}{r^2+s^2-(r+s)t}  \\[0.5em]
  n_1 &= \frac{(t^2-2rt+s^2-2rs-r^2)(rv-su)}{r^2+s^2-(r+s)t}  \\[0.5em]
  n_2 &= \frac{(t^2-2st-s^2-2rs+r^2)(rv-su)}{r^2+s^2-(r+s)t}  \\[0.5em]
  n_3 &= \frac{(-t^2-2st+s^2-2rt+r^2)(rv-su)}{r^2+s^2-(r+s)t}.
\end{align}

For example, $(r,s,t,u,v)=(1,-2,4,12,7)$ yields the equation (after clearing denominators)
$$3(217)^2 = 31^2+155^2+341^2.$$

If you want a primitive example, just make sure $rv-su=1$. For example, $(r,s,t,u,v)=(2,3,11,3,5)$ leads to the equation
$$3(67)^2=19^2+35^2+109^2.$$

Hope this helps!